# What is the best way to remove a large section of drywall, and hopefully reattach said section when done?

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall

I need to remove a chunk of drywall from the floor to the ceiling (see the attached picture - I'm referring to the area inside the blue lines). Ideally, I want to open exactly the space between the two studs (so I can replace the 3x10 HVAC duct, and run a conduit for networking cable).

Pretending the blue lines represent actual studs inside the wall.. if I cut the drywall just on the inside of each stud, it should be "easy" to remove in one piece. I would not have anything to attach it to put it back up, though (I might be able to sister the studs just to have something to mount the drywall to, but there probably won't be room.

Should I abandon hope of re-using the same section of drywall?

Can you suggest a method of cutting that is going to cause me the least pain?

[image]

Comment: Drywall is cheap. I personally would not expend the effort and hassle to reuse it to save not even $10 of material

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cut down the middle (more or less - leave the screws/nails on the part you are not removing unless they are way off-center) of the studs. Utility knife or "oscillating tool" if you have a yen for power tools. Mark all the screws/nail heads so you can avoid them when cutting. Or see below. You might (should) have extra studs by the window frame, giving you a larger framing target there.

Spare yourself the agony of trying to re-use the scrap. A whole sheet of new drywall is cheap compared to the labor involved in trying to remove it for reuse, rather than just ripping it out.

"Below:" Given that you are close to a corner, having bought a sheet, just go all the way to the corner with it. You'll have to redo all the way to the corner anyway if you cut that close to it.

Comment: I see what you’re saying about the corner… there are some upsides to cutting all the way… but that forces a new corner bead, skimming and paint on the next wall section as well.

Answer (score 2):

Cover everything from dust, there will be a lot.

Remove floor and ceiling mouldings.

Cut drywall with what is handy, knife, hand saw, power saw(not needed or recommended).  Find and remove screws/nails holding drywall at top and bottom.

Add nailing strips, attach everything back, tape and mud, repaint.

Comment: Suggest not removing base or crown. Stay a good 3” above/below to give room to tape and skim. And would also suggest hand tools, rather than power tools, because you have a chance of noticing power/water lines before you cut through them.